# How can I avoid responding to a select list onchange event when the user is still trying to select?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a handler associated with a `<select>` input's `change` event using jQuery:

```
$('#myList').change(function () {
   //...
});
```

When the user <kbd>Tab</kbd>s to the input and begins typing (without clicking to open the dropdown list), different browsers behave differently.

- In Firefox, the change event won't fire until the user either presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or in some other way changes focus away from the select list.
- In IE and Chrome, the change event is fired the moment the user types something that causes the item in the select list to change.

Because my `change` function performs an AJAX request, I would prefer to avoid having my function do anything while the user is typing or using the arrow keys to select a choice. However, I still want the change event to fire if the user selects a particular dropdown element with the mouse, or if the user hits the *enter* key. In other words, I'd like IE and Chrome to behave like Firefox.

Is there any (ideally simple) way to get the behavior I'm looking for?

Comment: maybe you can use `.blur` instead (which fires when the element loses focus)?

Comment: @Rodolfo: `.blur` would take care of one case. I also want to handle the case where the user really does intentionally select an item with the mouse or keyboard while the dropdown list is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED:

This should handle all of your requirements - http://jsfiddle.net/yfQ3V/4/

HTML:

```
<select data-value="one">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
</select>
<span></span>
```

JS:

```
var $select = $('select');
var $span = $('span');

var onChange = function () {
    setText();
};

var onKeyDown = function () {
    $select.off('change');
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if(keyCode == 13 || keyCode == 9) {
        $select.on('change', onChange).change(); 
    }
};

var onBlur = function () {
    if($select.val() != $select.data('value')) {
        setText();
    }
};

var setText = function () {
    var val = $select.val();
    $select.data('value', val);
    $span.text(val + ' - ' + new Date());   
};

$select.on('change', onChange)
       .on('keydown', onKeyDown)
       .on('blur', onBlur);
```

Comment: Please make sure you include your code in your answers. Fiddle's eventually expire and we want others to benefit from your knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: @mrtsherman jsFiddle fiddles are [permanent](https://twitter.com/?iid=am-66429244813216599221282233&nid=4%20status_user&uid=19116343&utm_content=profile#!/js_fiddle/status/137677807634481153).

Comment: @Šime Vidas - I've seen expired fiddles on SO before. I think the principle stands though. Always try to post code in SO.

Comment: This approach fails if I bring the dropdown into focus and use the arrow keys to select an item, then click outside of the dropdown.

Comment: This can be handled by attaching a blur event.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to accept this. Thanks for your contribution. It helped put me on the right path to solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a method that would cause *all* of my `<select>` controls to behave the same way, so that I wouldn't have to do a one-off piece of Javascript in each specific case. It's a little hacky, but at least I avoid repetitive code this way:

```
$(function() {
    // Make select lists in Chrome and IE behave more like Firefox: when they are focused
    // but not open and the user starts typing, we don't want the "change" event to fire
    // until the user has actually selected the value they want.
    var invokePendingChanges = function () {
        /// <summary>
        /// Event handler which checks "this" select box for a code that shows that changed
        /// events have been ignored. If it finds the code, it will invoke the 'change'
        /// event on the input.
        /// </summary>
        var t = $(this);
        if (t.data('change-pending')) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                t.data('change-pending', false);
                t.change();
            }, 0);
        }
    };
    $('select')
        .keydown(function(e) {
            // If the user hit the enter key, invoke pending changes.
            if (e.which == 13) {
                invokePendingChanges.call(this);
            } else {
                var t = $(this);
                // Be aware that date('events') isn't part of the official API, so it is subject
                // to change with future versions of jQuery.
                var allHandlers = t.data('events');
                var changeHandlers = allHandlers ? allHandlers['change'] : null;
                delete allHandlers['change'];
                t.change(function() {
                    t.data('change-pending', true);
                    return false;
                });

                var revert = function() {
                    allHandlers['change'] = changeHandlers;
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    t.off('blur', revert);
                };
                t.on('blur', revert);
                var timeout = setTimeout(revert, 0);
            }
        })
        .blur(invokePendingChanges);
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, but in later versions of jQuery you have to change it to var allHandlers = $._data(t.get(0), "events");

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, based off tjscience's answer.
It is implemented as a jquery function and works when bound to the same element more than once, with different handlers.

```
$.fn.dropDownChangeEventThatBehavesLikeFirefox = function (handler) {
/// <summary>The change() event behaviour for select boxes is different between Firefox and other browsers when using the keyboard.
/// Firefox only fires the change event when focus is lost, whereas other browsers fire the change event as soon the user uses the
/// keyboard to scroll through the select box.
/// This method should be used instead of the name jquery change() event to get consistent behaviour between Firefox and
/// other browsers (preferring the Firefox method).
/// </summary>
if ($.browser.mozilla) {
    // Firefox already behaves like we want it to, so get out of here.
    $(this).change(handler);
    return;
}

$(this).each(function () {

    var lastValue = $(this).val();

    $(this)
        .change(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            handler.apply(this);

            lastValue = $this.val();
        })
        .keydown(function (e) {
            var $this = $(this);

            $this.off('change');
            var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

            if (keyCode == 13 || keyCode == 9) {
                $this.on('change', handler).change();
            }
        })
        .on('blur click', function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            if ($this.val() != lastValue) {
                handler.apply(this);
                lastValue = $this.val();
            }
        });
});
};
```